# List length in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that compares coin flips between two players. I can't figure out why the following while loop prints "Game Over" even though the len of both lists is 5. When I check the len of either by typing len(player_x_army) it responds with the correct 5. If I change the "or" to "and" it works fine. Any help would be great.

```
while len(player_1_army) or len(player_2_army) == 0:
    print("Game Over")
```

Comment: `len(player_1_army) == 0`

Comment: Or `not player_1_army`; empty sequences evaluate `False` in a Boolean context. It's also not clear why that's a `while` loop. If there's only that one line inside it will never end.

Answer (score 0):

`len(player_1_army)` is not zero. Therefore, the first alternation in `OR` returns true. Thus the `while` loop is carried out.

In any boolean expression, if a `number` is present, it is evaluated to `number != 0`.

Instead you will need:

```
len(player_1_army) == 0 or len(player_2_army) == 0
```